# Is it possible to create a shared secret for multiple public keys (multiple users)?

Tags: node.js, cryptography

I am currently using ECDH and AES-256-GCM for E2EE. From messing around a little bit, it seems like this potentially only works between 2 single parties? What if I want to create a shared key between 5 people for example?

Lets say Bob started a group chat, he gathers all of the parties public keys and creates a shared key for them.

The `computeSecret` method seems to only accept a single public key.

Comment: Joux made DH for 3 parties...

Comment: @donoboro Did you find a workaround for the you problem using Node.js?